# Looping the query results of elements of an arraylist

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, jena

So I have this List strarray as input which has strings in the form of [Aa, Bb, Cc,..]
I need to run the same query for each of the elements of the list. Let the user choose which ones to keep and then add these results in a string.
The output of the string should look like this: "Aa.(Aaqueryresult1,Aaqueryresult2,...) \n
Bb.(Bbqueryresult1,Bbqueryresult2,...) \n Cc.Ccqueryresult1,Ccqueryresult2,...)"

With my code I get no results back, cause probably I am dealing problems with the loop. Any suggestions how could I make this work?

```
public static List<String> strarray = new ArrayList<String>() ;

for(int i =0;i<strarray.size(); i++){

        String selec1 = strarray.get(i);


        String queryString2 =
                "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +        
                "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> " +
                "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> " +
                "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> " +
                "PREFIX bi: <#> " +

    "SELECT ?X " +
    " WHERE {?X bi:has_input <"+selec1+">} " ;

        Query query2 = QueryFactory.create(queryString2);

        QueryExecution qe2 = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query2, model);
        com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet results3 =  qe2.execSelect();
        ResultSet results4 = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(results3);
        final ResultSet results5 = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(results4);

        System.out.println("==== Available Options ====");
        ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results4, query2);


        System.out.println( "== Select Option ==" );
        System.out.println( "== Type 0,1,2,3.. to choose ==" );

        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        final String inputs ;
        inputs = input.next();


   final String[] indices = inputs.split("\\s*,\\s*");


        final List<QuerySolution> selectedSolutions = new ArrayList<QuerySolution>( indices.length ) {{
            final List<QuerySolution> solutions = ResultSetFormatter.toList(results5);
            for ( final String index : indices ) {
                add( solutions.get( Integer.valueOf( index )));
            }
        }};


        String s = selectedSolutions.toString();


         String newstr;
          newstr = s.replaceAll("_", "");

          List<String> temp1 = new ArrayList<String>() ;

          Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#([^>]+)>");
           Matcher m = p.matcher(newstr);


           while (m.find()) {
               temp1.add(m.group(1));
            }         

           String selecfin = null;

           for(int j =0;j<temp1.size(); j++){
           String selecP = temp1.get(j);

           selecfin = selec1+".("+selecP+")";
           System.out.println(selecfin);
           }
           System.out.println(selecfin);
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by you get no result back? do you have an infinite loop? do you see any sysout?

Comment: Sorry I mean it runs but in the query it doesnt show any results inside the loop, while the query works properly. It is like it is not reading the elements of the strarraylist one by one, in order to query them, and give results. So below " ==== Available Options ====" i dont get any options. The resultset seems to have nothing init. So selec1 is not read properly inside the loop my guess

Comment: It is not an infinite loop. The input array has up to 10 elements

Answer (score 0):

Had problem with the input in the query. Forgot I replaced _ previously in the code. So the query wouldnt recognize the individual. Problem solved. Thanks